# How do I create windows service as “not stoppable” or “not configurable”?

Tags: windows, service, configuration

I have a console application,

I want it to run as service in windows machine

but I want it to be **“not stoppable”** and  **“not configurable”** after creating the service

Comment: Is this *your* application, i.e., do you have the source code?  Are you planning to make it into an actual service, or do you just want to run it "as if" it were a service using (for example) srvany or nssm?

Comment: ... what do you mean by "not configurable"?  You can change the permissions on a service to prohibit modification, but you shouldn't - and an administrator can always change them back again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response at first I have source code. I want to run it as service present I am using OpenSCManager() & CreateService() functions but I am confused in configuration of “Service Security and Access Rights

Comment: When you call OpenSCManager, you must specify at least `SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE`  because you want to create a service.  Simplest to specify `SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS`.  It is possible to change the permissions on the newly created service, but you shouldn't need to do so.  Do you realize that the service must call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` and have a `ServiceMain` function which registers a control handler, and so on?  The service itself determines whether or not it can be stopped, via the `dwControlsAccepted` field in the service status.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Make sure you understand, that any service is stoppable. With that out of the way, what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable, my guess was that he wants the service to not accept stop requests, so that (for example) the Services administrative tool won't show the "Stop the service" option.  Like the DCOM Server Process Launcher service, or the Group Policy Client.  Amit, can you confirm that this is what you meant?

Comment: Yas Harry Johnston  I want to do the same...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ...

Comment: thanks @HarryJohnston , by using 'dwControlsAccepted ' i am able to make services as not stoppable but still i am not able to block configuration.. still user can disable it by configuring it startup type as **disable** or **manual**  ..:(

Comment: Only a user with admin privileges should be able to do that.  If a non-admin user can change your service's startup type, your installer is doing something wrong.  If you add the code that creates the service to your question, I might be able to help.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for your support..I got the desire result for by 'Modifying the DACL for a Service' as mentioned  in this link [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684215(v=vs.85).aspx  once again thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same by referring this link  [click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684215(v=vs.85).aspx)

just we need to change GUEST to Administers  with its explicit access

```
  ` BuildExplicitAccessWithName(&ea, TEXT("GUEST"),
    SERVICE_START | SERVICE_STOP | READ_CONTROL | DELETE,
    SET_ACCESS, NO_INHERITANCE);`
```

Comment: If your code was explicitly granting permissions to GUEST then that is certainly the cause of your problem.  Note, however, that you *don't* need to change "GUEST" to "Administrators"; better to simply *remove that part of the code altogether* and just let Windows use the default permissions.